# window.print() not working as expected

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a beginner in JavaScript. So this question might sound silly. As I understand, `window.print()`, it prints the content or `innerHTML` in the body tag of the document in the window. In the following snippet,

My HTML Page :

```
 <html>

      <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">  
      </head>

      <body>
        <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
        <h2>Hi this is a header</h2>
        <h3>Hi this is a header 2</h3>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
      </body>

</html>
```

My Js code:(script.js) Here I am just making the body of the document as Hello world

```
var restore = document.body.innerHTML;
document.body.innerHTML = "Hello World";
window.print();
document.body.innerHTML = restore;
```

In this scenario, shouldn't hello world come up on the print page?

```
Why is

       Hello Plunker!
       Hi this is a header
       Hi, this is a header 2 coming up?
```

Edit: I had missed the last line where the innerhtml of the body is set back again to restore. Thanks for the help

Comment: which browser? Because firefox and chrome works as you expect

Answer (score 0):

hello world is coming for me and try codepen for good results. find out hear https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zWQdBW

```
    var restore = document.body.innerHTML;
document.body.innerHTML = "Hello World";
window.print();
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the events [`onbeforeprint`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeprint) and [`onafterprint`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onafterprint) (like in my example), or maybe even a special "print" CSS file.
Your approach might not work because the `window.print()` does not stop the code after it from executing.

```js
var previousBodyContent;
window.addEventListener("beforeprint", function() {
  previousBodyContent = document.body.innerHTML;
  document.body.innerHTML = "Hello World";
});

window.addEventListener("afterprint", function() {
  document.body.innerHTML = previousBodyContent;
});

window.print();
```

```html
<h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
<h2>Hi this is a header</h2>
<h3>Hi this is a header 2</h3>
```

Edit: Some more clarification on the behavior:

> As I understand, `window.print()`, it prints the content or `innerHTML` in the body tag of the document in the window.

Not exactly, `window.print()` just tells the browser to open the print dialog. The same as if you go into "menu" > "print..." or press `ctrl + p`.

The content of the page at the time you call `window.print()` is not necessarily what you see in the print preview or what gets printed, if you change the content quickly after the call.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but would appreciate it if u would explain why it happened,  like the interior functioning of it, rather than a soln

Comment: @suhastangadle I added some more clarification.